# javascript: how to change multi input values depends on other span data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function on page loading that changes input values , the input values are get changed but all are the same value.

here is my code snippets:

```
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#f5f5dc" data-color="bezhevyi" style="background-color: #f5f5dc">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="color" class="colors">
</span>
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#ffffff" data-color="belyi" style="background-color: #ffffff">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="color" class="colors">
</span>
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#add8e6" data-color="goluboi" style="background-color: #add8e6">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" name="color" class="colors">
</span>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('colors');
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-color');
    for(z = 0; z < y.length; z++){
        for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].value = y[z].dataset.color;
            // console.log(y[z].dataset.color);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, sure.  You're looping over all the x for every y, and setting all the x each time.

Comment: Ooopsy, sorry its my mistake, i didn't noticed that , now it works, the `for(z=0;)` just enough :). Thank you for your interest ;)

Comment: make sure to declare `z` and `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //select all the colors, and set their value
  $('.colors').val(function(){
    //return the parent toggle-color's data-color to be set for each input
    return $(this).closest('.toggle-color').data('color');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#f5f5dc" data-color="bezhevyi" style="background-color: #f5f5dc">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" class="colors">
</span>
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#ffffff" data-color="belyi" style="background-color: #ffffff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" class="colors">
</span>
<span class="toggle-color" data-hex="#add8e6" data-color="goluboi" style="background-color: #add8e6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" class="colors">
</span>
```